# How long do warmup epochs take to be at normal speed?

Tags: local-cluster

I am running a global private cluster and have `--enable-warmup-epochs` enabled in my genesis. How long does it take to get to normal speed?

The helpfile shows:

`--enable-warmup-epochs    When enabled epochs start short and will grow. Useful for warming up stake quickly during development`

Also, can it be removed and what would be the easiest process for all the connected RPC and validators to get the modified genesis.bin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** run the `getEpochSchedule` RPC method on your running validator and get the `firstNormalSlot`, which will be the first slot after the warmup period ends.

Once the network starts, you cannot modify the genesis and be able to resume the network from where you left off, you have to start from scratch.

**Long answer:** you can find the code that determines how long the warmup period lasts [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/sdk/program/src/epoch_schedule.rs). Browse the code a bit and read the comments, as it offers some info you might find relevant (line 52 has the actual formula).

I moved the `custom()` fn in [the rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=94d05d1c5c913ee653ef91af9258495d) so you can determine yourself how long it takes. Modify the arguments of the `custom()` fn called in `main`, run the code and it will output the epoch schedule.

Essentially you'll want to modify the `slots_per_epoch` (set to `100000` when you open the link), which is the first argument of the function and in the output the most relevant info for your question is `first_normal_slot`, which represents how many slots it takes until the warmup period ends and when the epoch schedule goes to normal.

If you don't know the `slots_per_epoch` of your genesis, it is the value passed via `--slots-per-epoch` to `solana-genesis` command. It is also present in the [`getEpochSchedule` RPC method](https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getepochschedule)